# Visual Studio Code use on remote files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to use the python extension to edit files that reside on a remote server? I have tried NFS and remoteFS, but I do not see any way to get Intellisense working using the remote installation. I normally edit and test on a windows machine, while the target runs on Linux. 
I realise this is not limited to this extension, but is a more general issue.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I do this (editing remote files from windows with visual studio code) and I have no problem. Can you explain more?

Comment: It very might well be my setup of Visual studio and /or Linux system or NFS. The general problem (I think not limited to Python), is dat VS Code does not know about the includes and libraries used remotely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Code now officially supports this using an Extension: [Remote SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh)

Read the release notes here: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development

> Today we're excited to announce the preview of three new extensions for Visual Studio Code that enable seamless development in Containers, **remotely on physical or virtual machines**, and with the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). You can get started right away by installing the [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack).

Comment: These latest extensions from Microsoft (to be used with the Insiders version for now) indeed solve all issues I had. Great stuff!!

Comment: It should be noted that these extensions are still in an early phase: until a few days ago they only ran on the Insiders builds. Now, as of VS Code 1.35, [they can also be used with the stable build](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35#_contributions-to-extensions), but the extensions themselves are still marked as "Preview" (the message you've quoted also mentions it, but it's easy to miss it). Those who need stability and reliability might want to wait some more.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I'm using a Linux Hosted virtual machine which has a similar setup as the target. This works surprisingly well. It is a shame VMware 12 removed support for unity.

Answer (score 1):

I use [SSHFS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh) ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS)) ([github repo](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs))

```
sshfs OWN_USER@SERVER:/PATH_TO_FILES/ MOUNT_POINT
```

This makes the remote files visible to any program on your computer, as-if they were local files, through a virtual "FUSE" filesystem.

If your own user can't access the files (you need `root` or some other user), you can `sudo` like so:

```
sshfs -o sftp_server="sudo -u SYSTEM_USER /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server" \
    OWN_USER@SERVER:/PATH_TO_FILES/ MOUNT_POINT
```

You can install sshfs for Linux, Mac, or Windows, check out Digital Ocean's guide in my first link.

Don't forget to `umount`, `fusermount -u`, or *eject* that MOUNT_POINT once you're done.

I don't know if other VS Code plugins like IntelliSense would work with this. They *should* because the sshfs makes the files visible just like any others. But, it would require that the python tool chain you have installed locally be the same on your laptop and on the server.  It'd be interesting to find out.

Or, Microsoft just announced [some new plugins on the way](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/05/02/remote-development)

Comment: SSHFS is also an interesting option for many remote challenges, but Microsoft's recent solution of having remote extensions is very elegant and seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are some. I used [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liximomo.sftp). It allows to synchronize code between local and remote server.
You will have to keep copy on local host and it can be configured to automatically update code on remote.

Answer (score 0):

https://gurumantra.themillennialpost.info/2020/05/edit-linux-files-remotely-in-vscode.html
Download and install vscode in your localPc if you don’t have it. (click here to download vscode)

Summary :

1. Install Vscode, remote vscode – LocalPC
2. Install ssh and Rmate – RemotePc
3. Ready to access files/data

Detailed Steps:
https://gurumantra.themillennialpost.info/2020/05/edit-linux-files-remotely-in-vscode.html